# Azure Web Job-The remote server returned 404

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a continuos running web job which listens to a `start` queue and a stop `queue` with their respective functions. There are 3 predefined process in the web job and the `start` queue contains a message which mentions the process name to be started while the `stop` queue contains a message which mentions the process name to be stopped.

When ever the webjob stops a process it crashes and restarts with the above exception since last 4 weeks.

```
Executing: 'Functions.StartProcess' because New queue message detected on 'start'.
Updated the status of Process A to 1
Process A Started
Process A processed 200 records
Process A processed 200 records
Process A processed 200 records
Process A processed 200 records
Process A processed 200 records
Executing: 'Functions.StopProcess' because New queue message detected on 'stop'.
Process A stopped
Disposed Process A
Updated the status of Process A to 3

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobSharedImpl.<DeleteBlobImpl>b__1b(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.EndDelete(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Protocols.PersistentQueueWriter`1.<DeleteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.CompositeFunctionInstanceLogger.<DeleteLogFunctionStartedAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueTriggerExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.BackgroundExceptionDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Throw>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The webjob does not even contain any code to delete a blob file.

While debugging, the debugger does not point to any specific line while throwing the exception and hence I have no clue as to what is the actual cause.

**PS** : It used to run perfectly prior to that and every function's body is enclosed in try catch block. The catch block does not rethrow the exception but just logs the stacktrace and continues.

**EDIT**

I had to check if the below containers were there

[image]

in the webjob's storage and also updated the `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` nuget package. *I am really not sure if this fixes the problem for sure though*.

Comment: Can you check the container name for the blob that failed?

Comment: I don't have any container created nor am I trying to delete anything. I have no clue what the web job is trying to delete. I don't have any blob triggers also. The storage has the default containers which are created by the azure webjob sdk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you were right, you do in fact need to **manually** create the blob containers, **or** publish the web job, in which case it looks like the environment will create the containers for you.

When I tried it out initially, I did the publish first, and it worked like a charm. Second project, I am doing it differently, so I ran the console app first, and it kept failing with 404.

So, you need to create:

- azure-webjobs-dashboard
- azure-webjobs-hosts
- azure-jobs-hosts-archive
- azure-jobs-hosts-output

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I would add.. if you wish to do it in C# 
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =...;
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            //the container for this is companystyles
            blobClient.GetContainerReference("azure-webjobs-dashboard").CreateIfNotExists();
            blobClient.GetContainerReference("azure-webjobs-hosts").CreateIfNotExists();
            blobClient.GetContainerReference("azure-jobs-hosts-archive").CreateIfNotExists();
            blobClient.GetContainerReference("azure-jobs-hosts-output").CreateIfNotExists();

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error.

What worked for me was updating the `WindowsAzure.Storage` package in my case from `4.3.0` to `7.1.2`, but I would go with latest or whatever your other WebJobs are using (if they are running without issue).

Answer (score 0):

Our WebJob encountered this issue in the middle of a Friday afternoon. Previous deployment was 9 days prior and the WebJob functioned up until it suddenly did not. Not sure why it stopped working.
After much reading I believe this means simply that it cannot connect to the storage account for one reason or another, while initializing the WebJob.

Our solution was to add the AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard connection strings to the connection strings [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-connectionstrings) of the App Service via our ARM Template.

```
       "AzureWebJobsDashboard": {
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccount')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]",
          "type": "Custom"
        },
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": {
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccount')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]",
          "type": "Custom"
        }
```

These values already existed in the app settings config of the App Service, which must have been how it was functioning prior.

We did update libraries per other suggestions to some other answers to this issue. That alone did not solve it.
We also migrated the WebJob from .Net Framework 4.5 to 4.6 to match the rest of the solution, though I don't think this was really part of the fix, just FYI in case it helps someone.