# Azure Web Jobs Throws Azure Storage 404 Not Found

Tags: azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have webjobs deployed in Azure and it was previously working before but after our latest deployment we are experiencing issues that our webjobs are throwing "Azure Storage Exception".

```
  [03/25/2016 01:38:26 > 5f45b8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
    [03/25/2016 01:38:40 > 5f45b8: SYS INFO] Run script 'ListNet.JobController.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
    [03/25/2016 01:38:40 > 5f45b8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
    [03/25/2016 01:38:41 > 5f45b8: INFO] Found the following functions:
    [03/25/2016 01:38:41 > 5f45b8: INFO] ListNet.JobController.Functions.ManualTrigger
    [03/25/2016 01:38:41 > 5f45b8: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.ManualTrigger' because This was function was programmatically called via the host APIs.
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] 
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobSharedImpl.<DeleteBlobImpl>b__1b(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.EndDelete(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Protocols.PersistentQueueWriter`1.<DeleteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.CompositeFunctionInstanceLogger.<DeleteLogFunctionStartedAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.HeartbeatFunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.AbortListenerFunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ShutdownFunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<CallAsyncCore>d__7.MoveNext()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Call(MethodInfo method)
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: ERR ]    at ListNet.JobController.Program.Main()
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
    [03/25/2016 01:41:12 > 5f45b8: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

I looked into this similar issue but I already have these containers on my azure storage:

[Azure Web Job-The remote server returned 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756357/azure-web-job-the-remote-server-returned-404)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkCab.png

Notes

- I use manual trigger
- I create a default web job and run it successfully

Comment: The "AzureWebJobsStorage" storage connection string is correct and not being overridden by something unexpected in the WebApp's portal application settings?

Comment: AzureStorageConnection string is correct. The connection string on my AzureWebJob Configuration is the same as my connection string on the app.config

should I remove this connection string from Configure tab of azure web job?

Comment: It now works when I remove the connection string in the config.

Comment: The portal wepapp settings should override the web.config/app.config...

Comment: is it safe to remove it since I don't have a web app deployed. We only use the web app to manage web jobs

Comment: I have **AzureWebJobsDashboard** connection string on my web app's web config and removing this will make my webjob succeed but I will not have a reference to the logs that shows what function did the webjob triggers

Comment: Does your dashboard point to the same storage account?

Comment: Yes, my dashboard point to the same storage account

Comment: Something is fishy. As per your log the web job failed **after** it triggered the function __ManualTrigger__. Generally if the web job can't connect to the storage account it fails to even **before** executing any function Can you please show some code?

Comment: That is correct @Sandesh. This is really annoying, what code would you want to see?

Comment: `public class Program
{
        // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
        // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
        private static void Main()
        {
            var host = new JobHost();
            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            //host.RunAndBlock();
            host.Call(typeof (Functions).GetMethod("ManualTrigger"));
        }
}`

Comment: `public static void ManualTrigger(TextWriter log)
        {
            var master = SaveMasterFileToStorage();
            log.WriteLine("End of saving master, total is {0}", master.MasterPagination.TotalRecords);
            DataProcessingService.RemoveExpiredListings(master);
            log.WriteLine("End of removing expired listings");
            log.WriteLine("Done!");
        }`

Comment: Can you please put this code in the question itself so that it is better readable. Also one small suggestion. Can you wrap your code inside ManualTrigger function inside try/catch block and see if you get the same exception. Instead of using ***log*** please use ***Console.WriteLine***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of verification I have found out that the cause of this issue is duplicate nuget package dependencies. It turns out that I have multiple nuget package (Newtonsoft.Json) with different versions (e.g: 1.1, 1.2).

On why nuget is doing that, I have no idea.

Comment: I was getting this same error.

What worked for me was updating the `WindowsAzure.Storage` package in my case from `4.3.0` to `7.1.2`, but I would go with latest or whatever your other WebJobs are using (if they are running without issue).