# Azure WebJob QueueTrigger Throwing StorageException 404 Not Found

Tags: azure, exception, triggers, queue, http-status-code-404

I am working with Azure Queues, Controlling them using WebJob, In the functions file i have one QueueTrigger function, which fires up when AzureQueue receives some message.

Now the problem is that function (QueueTrigger) executes successfully, I have setup proper exception handling inside queue trigger function, everything executed without any errors. But when QueueTrigger function ends, code is throwing exception. Storage Exception 404 Not found.

and that message is not getting deleted from queue. Next time when i run job it is still fetching the old message. I have manually created storage containers

- azure-jobs-host-archive
- azure-jobs-host-output
- azure-webjobs-dashboard
- azure-webjobs-hosts

I have seen in one post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756357/azure-web-job-the-remote-server-returned-404) but this does not help at all.

I have no idea how to tackle this exception or why this exception in throwing in the code.

Thank you

Eman

Comment: Would you be able to share your code at all?

Comment: Hi Martyn, I was able to solve the problem by my self. When I have updated all the following packages the problem solved automatically.

Comment: - Microsoft.WindowAzure.Storage
- Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host

Answer (score 0):

After updating the following packages the problem get solved.

- Microsoft.WindowAzure.Storage
- Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host